# How to create an admin user, and so on in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-security

I can not quite understand how to make users with different privileges (administrator, student, teacher), here are the rules:

```
{"rules": 
    {"authentication": 
        {"users": 
            {"$uid": {
                ".read": "auth.uid == $uid || root.child('authentication').child('users').child('auth.uid').child('isAdmin').val() == true",
                ".write": "newData.parent().parent().parent().child('authentication').child('users').child('auth.uid').child('isAdmin').val() == true",
                ".indexOn": [
                    "email"
                ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

user: [link screen user](http://prntscr.com/d1qg4k)

Realtime Database:

```
{
 "users" : {
 "-KVVe4Ncd5Qnm5r37zVp" : {
   "email" : "admin@gmail.com",
   "isAdmin" : true,
   "name" : "admin"
 },
  "-KVVeADyh07mBXBFImtq" : {
   "email" : "djvang92@gmail.com",
   "isAdmin" : true,
   "name" : "Ivan"
  }
 }
}
```

Firebase script:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAfeEpMopsPWnowiv1uEWYINgk6V_ohvG4",
  authDomain: "spalah-1358.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://spalah-1358.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "spalah-1358.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "300000265085"
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)


export const db = firebase.database();

export const auth = firebase.auth()



console.log(auth);

// var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
// var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
// var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
// var provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();




export default {

  // User object will let us check authentication status
  user: {
    authenticated: false,
    data: null,
    message: ''
  },
  login(context, creds, redirect) {
    console.log('Login...');
    let self = this;
    let email = creds.email;
    let password = creds.password;
    let promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    console.log(email, password);

    // Redirect to a specified route
    if(redirect) {
       // context.$router.go(redirect) 
       // console.log(context.$router);       
    }

    promise
    .then(user => {
       self.user.authenticated = true
       self.user.message = false
    })
    .catch(e => {
      self.user.message = e.message
      console.log(e);
    })

  },
  signup(context, creds, redirect) {
    console.log('Sign Up...');
    let email = creds.email
    let password = creds.password
    let promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    promise
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        self.user.message = false
      })
      .catch(e => {
        self.user.message = e.message
        console.log(e);
      })
  },
  logout() {
    let self = this
    auth.signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
      console.log('Log-out successful');
      self.user.authenticated = false
    }, function(error) {
      // An error happened.
      console.log('Log-out error');
    });
  },
  provider(context, creds, redirect) {
    let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

    auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      // Accounts successfully linked.
      var credential = result.credential;
      var user = result.user;
      // ...
      console.log(credential);
      console.log(user.photoURL);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      // ...
      console.log(error);
    });

  },
  checkAuth() {
    let self = this
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        console.log('Connect:', user);
        self.user.authenticated = true
        self.user.data = user
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        console.log('No connect:');
        self.user.authenticated = false
        self.user.data = null
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I can not figure out how to keep track of it in Javascript ...
(Do vue.js on application) may have any examples of how to make users with different ...
Thank you!

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Also: if you have problems making a specific piece of JavaScript work, show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 

Thank you. I am newbie.
updated question